# ember.js Sorting model in controller

Tags: sorting, ember.js, controller, computed-properties

ember.js version: 2.18.0

model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  songs: DS.hasMany('song')
})
```

controller:

```
export default Controller.extend({
  sortBy: ['name:asc', 'description:asc'],
  sortedBands: computed.sort('model', 'sortBy')
}
```

ember gave me the following error:

```
Only string, number, symbol, boolean, null, undefined, and function are allowed as default properties ember/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects
```

Comment: Are you sure that is an error? What exactly does not work? I know what you posted as a rule from a style guide (linked in the answer by Engwan), but that's just a recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you're setting an array as the default value of a property (`sortBy`) in an Object (`Controller`).

You can set the array value in the `init` hook.

```
export default Controller.extend({
  sortedBands: computed.sort('model', 'sortBy'),

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.sortBy = ['name:asc', 'description:asc'];
  }
}
```

Check this link for more info: https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects.md

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for using empty js object as default property for a controller variable.

Object.freeze() worked for me.

Another way to fix your issue:

```
export default Controller.extend({
  sortedBands: Object.freeze(['name:asc', 'description:asc']),
  ...
}
```